# limit without expansion

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, definite-integrals, fractions

I was solving this limit  instead of using sum of expansion i  did this and got zero  but answer is 1/5 by expansion why this is wrong
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty } \frac{1^4 + 2^4 + \ldots +  n^4}{n^5}$$

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty } \frac{n^4( \frac{1^4}{n^4} + \frac{2^4}{n^4} +\ldots + 1 )}{n^5}$$

$$= \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty } \frac{( \frac{1^4}{n^4} + \frac{2^4}{n^4} +\ldots + 1 )}{n}$$

$$= \frac{(0 + 0 +0 \ldots + 1 )}{n} = 0$$ this is how i got  ,

Comment: Infinite sum is not "permeable" with limit, that's the reason

Comment: permeable can you explain little bit plz

Comment: Sorry for informal wording, but what I actually mean is that $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sum_{i=1}^n a_i(n)$ does not necessarily equal to $\sum_{i=1}^\infty \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} a_i(n)$

Comment: still not got it , sorry :|   , so is there any other method  without expansion  ?

Comment: My words just want to show why the "swapping" of limit sign and the summation sign is not allowed in math.  And for method without expansion, the answer below (with integration) is the best.  You may want to refer to the **first page** of the article: https://www.dawsoncollege.qc.ca/public/programs/disciplines/math/coursesupplements/supplementary_notes_-_riemann_sum.pdf to understand more about the best answer below (for the integration method)

Comment: @ElfHog: although I haven't seen "permeable" in analysis / calculus texts, it does convey the idea here. +1 for your comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were going right till the very last step. You need to apply the limit after computing the sum. The limit converts to Riemann integral:

$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{k^4}{n^5} = \int_{0}^{1} x^4 dx = \frac{1}{5}$$

---

Since you are not familiar with integration, another method is to find $\sum_{k=1}^{n} k^4$ explicitly. Only the leading coefficient, ie the coefficient of $n^5$ needs to be found.

$$\sum_{k=1}^nk^4=\frac1{30}n(n+1)(2n+1)(3n^2+3n-1)$$

So we can write $\sum_{k=1}^nk^4 = \frac{n^5}{5} + \frac{n^4}{2} + \frac{n^3}{3} -\frac{n}{30}$. Thus if you compute the limit

$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{k^4}{n^5} = \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{\frac{n^5}{5} + \frac{n^4}{2} + \frac{n^3}{3} -\frac{n}{30}}{n^5}\\
\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{\frac{1}{5} + \frac{1}{2n} + \frac{1}{3n^2} -\frac{1}{30n^4}}{1} = \frac{1}{5}$$

Comment: reimann  integral  , its not in my syllabus i did not got where i did wrong sir

Comment: even if i apply limit  1/ infinity , it go towards zero

Comment: Ok alternative way is to note that $\sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{k^4}{n^5} = \frac{\frac{n^5}{5} + an^{4} + ...}{n^5}$

Comment: sir  , where iam wrong everything seems fine , i took common correctly

Comment: @sumitgoyal You will know where you went wrong when you compute $\sum_{k=1}^{n} k^4$. It will be a quintic, ie coefficient of $n^5$ on numerator is finite nonzero. Limit thus is finite nonzero.

Comment: i didnot get why should i compute , if i multiply back iam getting everything as same  , can you tell me how you would have taken common

Comment: plzzzz iam not getting

Comment: @sumit see edit. You need to divide by $n^5$

Comment: in question i mentioned i  dont have to apply expansion of sum of  4 power of 1st natural number , how to solve without this ?

Answer (score 5):

Also, you can use Stolz: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stolz%E2%80%93Ces%C3%A0ro_theorem
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow+\infty}\frac{1^4+2^4+...+n^4}{n^5}=\lim_{n\rightarrow+\infty}\frac{n^4}{n^5-(n-1)^5}=\frac{1}{5}.$$

Comment: sir why  my solution is giving wrong , any reason plz exxplain

Comment: Because theorems about limits don't work for infinitely many sequences.

Comment: hha  King Tut true that :P  sir  i have not applied any theorem just took  n^4 common remaining terms will go towards zero , my whole childhood was a lie :}

Comment: But you want that $n\rightarrow+\infty$,

Comment: any link that says  it  thanks advance

Comment: You can take also the following counterexample for your reasoning: $1=\frac{1}{n}+\frac{1}{n}+...+\frac{1}{n}\rightarrow0.$. I took $n$ fractions. What do you think?

Comment: when n -> infinity  then   1  = 0

Comment: it says that your reasoning is wrong.

Comment: ok , why sir ji

Comment: Because $1\neq0$. What do you think?

Comment: hmm sorry iam in total confusion looks like i have to use only expansion it is only method :|

Comment: I think by Stolz you can get the answer immediately.

Comment: sumit - for intuition, note that each term contributes a tiny bit to the entire. If each contribution is taken, it may happen that limit becomes finite. By applying limit first, you neglect that tiny contribution of each term.

Comment: yes i reffered link , but you are getting different from general form provided on wiki

Comment: I took $a_n=1^4+2^4+...+n^4$ and $b_n=n^5$. Thus, $\frac{a_n-a_{n-1}}{b_n-b_{n-1}}=\frac{n^4}{n^5-(n-1)^5}.$

Comment: I think this is also a nice way. liked answer michael :)

Comment: a(n) = 1^4 + 2^4 +--- +n^4  , how a(n) - a(n-1) = n^4  ,  i got denominator part plz explain

Comment: Because $a_n-a_{n-1}=1^4+2^4+...+(n-1)^4+n^4-(1^4+2^4+...+(n-1)^4)=n^4.$

Comment: thankuuu sirrrrrr  god bless you i got it :)

Comment: You are welcome!

Comment: sir this theorem is only for infinite series right

Comment: Yes, of course. It's a very useful theorem.

Comment: wait sir how you got 1/5  , i took common but iam not getting 1/5

Comment: Because $\frac{n^4}{n^5-(n-1)^5}=\frac{n^4}{n^5-(n^5-5n^4+10n^3-10n^2+5n-1)}=\frac{1}{5-\frac{10}{n}+\frac{10}{n^2}-\frac{5}{n^3}+\frac{1}{n^4}}\rightarrow\frac{1}{5}.$

Comment: thankyou , i think it is high level  mathematics iam prepairing for GATE exam  for Mtech  ,  stolz theorem is not for me right ?

Comment: Why? I don't agree with you. Read a proof of this theorem. It's something beautiful! After this just use this theorem for calculating of limits.

Comment: Best way at all!

Comment: @sumitgoyal: it's a typical theorem seen in most undergraduate courses in mathematics (BSc in India). You should already be aware of Cesaro-Stolz if you are preparing for GATE. Do have a look at wiki for more details on this theorem and probably you will find hundreds of limits evaluated using this theorem on this website.

Comment: Paramanand Singh   i have series of iit lectures , sir didnot taught  it   so i thought that its for high level only

Answer (score 4):

You can’t do this step

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty } \frac{ \frac{1^4}{n^4} + \frac{2^4}{n^4} +...+1 }{n}\color{red}{=\frac{0 + 0 +0 +...+1 }{n}= 0} $$

since you have infinitely many terms which tend to 0 and their sum not necessarily is $0$.

Think to $\sum_1^{\infty} \frac1k$ which diverges.

Comment: i want more explanation please

Comment: when you have infinite terms you are not allowed to first take the limit of each term of the sum and then sum the sum ofvthese limits, the algebraic rule for sum applies only if the sum is finite

Comment: thanku now i got it  :)

Comment: It’s good. Well done! Bye

Answer (score 1):

If we define 
$$
s(n):=\sum_{k=0}^nk^4
$$
you want to calculate 
$$\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}\frac{\sum\limits_{k=0}^nk^4}{n^5}
$$
You say
$$\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}\left(\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{ k^4}{n^5}\right)=\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}\left(\sum_{k=0}^n \lim\limits_{m\to \infty}\frac{ k^4}{m^5}\right)
$$
but this transformation is generally not allowed.

---

We know that $s$ is a polynomial of degree $5$. If you don't know let us assume that this is the case. So we define
$$
p(n):=b_0+b_1n+b_2n(n-1)+b_3n(n-1)(n-2)+b_4n(n-1)(n-2)(n-3)+b_5n(n-1)(n-2)(n-3)(n-4)    
$$
and we can calculate the the $b_i$ successively:

$$
p(0)=s(0) \implies b_0=0\\
p(1)=s(1) \implies b_0+b_1=1 \implies b_1=1\\
p(2)=s(1)+2^4 \implies b_0+2b_1+2b_2=17\implies b_2=\frac{15}{2}
$$
and further
$$
b_3=\frac{25}{3}\\
b_4=\frac{5}{2}\\
b_5=\frac{1}{5}
$$

So we have

$$s(n)=\frac{1}{5}n^5+p_4x^4+p_3x^3+p_2x^2+p_1x+p_0$$

The coefficients $p_4,\ldots,p_0$ are easily to calculate but we don't need there exact values.

So $$\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}\frac{\sum_{k=0}^nk^4}{n^5}\\
=\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}\frac{\frac{1}{5}n^5+p_4x^4+p_3x^3+p_2x^2+p_1x+p_0}{n^5}=\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}\left(\frac{1}{5}+p_4\frac{1}{n}+p_3\frac{1}{n^2}+p_2\frac{1}{n^3}+p_1\frac{1}{n^4}+p_0\frac{1}{n^5}\right)\\
=\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}1
+p_4\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}\frac{1}{n}
+p_3\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}\frac{1}{n^2}
+p_2\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}\frac{1}{n^3}
+p_1\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}\frac{1}{n^4}
+p_0\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}\frac{1}{n^5}\\
=1+0+0+0+0+0$$

Here we apply the well known laws about  limits.

---

If you don'believe that $s(n)$ is a polynomial of degree $5$ the you can proof it by induction (or look up the formula at [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faulhaber%27s_formula#Examples)).

You can calculate the missing coefficient $p_i$ and get the polynomial
$${{n^5}\over{5}}+{{n^4}\over{2}}+{{n^3}\over{3}}-{{n}\over{30}}$$

Then you use

$$\left({{\left(n+1\right)^5}\over{5}}+{{\left(n+1\right)^4}\over{2}}+{{
 \left(n+1\right)^3}\over{3}}-{{n+1}\over{30}}\right) - \left({{n^5}\over{5}}+{{n^4}\over{2}}+{{n^3}\over{3}}-{{n}\over{30}}\right)= (n+1)^4
$$

---

(without proof)

Let's calculate the values 
$$s(0),\;s(1),\;s(2),\ldots$$
the differences 
$$s(1)-s(0),\;s(2)-s(1),\;s(3)-s(2),\;\ldots$$
of these values, the differences of these differences and so on, as shown in the table below.

```
 0     1    17    98   354   979  2275  4676  8772 15333 
    1    16    81   256   625  1296  2401  4096  6561
      15    65   175   369   671  1105  1695  2465
         50   110   194   302   434   590   770
            60    84   108   132   156   180
               24    24    24    24    24   
                   0     0     0     0
```

If $s(n)$ is a polynomial we eventually reach a line that only contains $0$. If the degree of $s$ is $d$ then it is the line $d+2$. Note that the left site of the triangle consists of the numbers

$$0, 1, 15, 50, 60, 24, 0,\ldots$$

Also note that

$$\frac{0}{0!}, \frac{1}{1!}, \frac{15}{2!}, \frac{50}{3!}, \frac{60}{4!}, \frac{24}{5!}, 0\ldots$$

are the coefficients $b_i$ of the Newton polynomial $p(x)$.

So the coefficient $b_5$ that we needed for the calculation of our limit  can be found quickly by calculation these differences.

A proof can be found in

```
van der Waerden
Algebra 1
Achte Auflage der Modernen Algebra
Springer Verlag Berlin - Heidelberg - New York  1971
pp 88-92
```

or anywhere in the internet.

Answer (score 0):

If
$m > 1$ then
$k^m
\lt \int_k^{k+1} x^m dx
\lt (k+1)^m
$.

Summing the left inequality
from $1$ to $n-1$,

$\begin{array}\\
\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}k^m
&\lt \sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\int_k^{k+1} x^m dx\\
&= \int_1^{n} x^m dx\\
&= \dfrac{x^{m+1}}{m+1}\big|_1^{n}\\
&< \dfrac{n^{m+1}-1}{m+1}+(n+1)^m\\
&< \dfrac{n^{m+1}}{m+1}\\
\text{so}\\
\sum_{k=1}^{n}k^m
&< \dfrac{n^{m+1}}{m+1}+n^m\\
\text{so}\\
\dfrac1{n^{m+1}}\sum_{k=1}^{n}k^m
&< \dfrac{1}{m+1}+\dfrac1{n}\\
\end{array}
$

Similarly,
summing the right inequality
from $0$ to $n-1$,

$\begin{array}\\
\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}(k+1)^m
&\gt \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\int_k^{k+1} x^m dx\\
&= \int_0^{n} x^m dx\\
&= \dfrac{x^{m+1}}{m+1}\big|_0^{n}\\
&= \dfrac{n^{m+1}}{m+1}\\
\text{so}\\
\sum_{k=1}^{n}k^m
&> \dfrac{n^{m+1}}{m+1}\\
\text{so}\\
\dfrac1{n^{m+1}}\sum_{k=1}^{n}k^m
&> \dfrac{1}{m+1}\\
\end{array}
$

Therefore
$0
\lt \dfrac1{n^{m+1}}\sum_{k=1}^{n}k^m
- \dfrac{1}{m+1}
\lt \dfrac1{n}
$
so
$\lim_{n \to \infty} \dfrac1{n^{m+1}}\sum_{k=1}^{n}k^m
=\dfrac1{m+1}$.

Note:
Nothing original here,
though I took pains
to make the result
come about
as painlessly as possible.

Comment: i think you answered other question here is it ??

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that while each term tends to zero, the *number* of terms tends to infinity at the same time.

The rule “the limit of a sum is the sum of the limits” only applies if you have a finite sum with a fixed number of terms (each of which has a finite limit).

(Also, you can't really write
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} (\dots) = (\text{some expression involving $n$})$$
since there can be no $n$ left in your expression *after* you have let $n \to \infty$. The symbol $n$ stands for the *same* number everywhere, so you can't selectively let some $n$ tend to $\infty$ while leaving other $n$ unaffected.)

Comment: thanks sir ji...